# Break an Array of Integers into the Maximum Number of Subarrays with Exact Sums

Tags: arrays, algorithm, discrete-mathematics

If I have array of integers like...

{3,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,9}

I want to create the maximum number of subarrays that add to exactly 40 with each element being used only once. Repeat numbers is fine as long as not all the repeats have been used.

It's easy finding a maximum number of subarrays and finding subarrays of 40, however the problem is finding subarrays that provide 40 and doesn't prevent other subarrays of 40 being formed.

I need an output of subsets formed.

It sounds very similar to the partitioning problem.

Is there a name to this problem? Anyone have a solution?

Comment: By subarrays do you mean *subsets* or *slices*? If the former, it is clearly and NP-hard problem since it is at least as hard as the subset-sum problem.

Comment: Sets of integers that's allows duplicates that is taken from the larger set.

Comment: So you are looking for partitions of a multiset which maximizes the number of pieces which sum to 1. It could be thought of as a bin-packing problem where the objective is to maximize the number of *full* bins rather than to minimize the total number of bins

Comment: I meant "sum to 40" in my previous comment. There is something called the *dual bin packing problem* in the literature where the goal is to maximize the number of bins which are either full or, oddly enough, over-full. Surely someone somewhere must have studied the variation where the constraint is to equal the capacity rather than exceed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not efficient perhaps but you can do the following -- find multiples of 40 for which the subset-sum problem can be solved, starting with the largest multiple of 40 <= total sum and working down. Then once you find a subset that sums to that multiple of 40, solve the appropriate k-partition problem for that subset. For example, if the multiple of 40 is 120 solve (if possible) the 3-partition problem of breaking it into 3 sets of equal size. But note that it isn't enough to identify a single subset that sums to 120 before ruling out a solution for 120 -- you would have to look at all subsets that sum to 120 since one such subset might have a solvable 3-partition problem while another such subset doesn't.

Comment: I like that solution John, that's good enough for my purposes. I've been thinking about the best way to solve this problem for about an hour, but I'm ready to go sub-optimal!

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic programming. Let `dp[j]- the max number of segments that sum to 40 s.t. no index of segments is larger than j`. Then you can do the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++)
    for(int j = i, sum = numbers[j]; j >= 0 && sum <= 40; j--, sum += numbers[j]) {
        if(sum == 40) {
            dp[i] = max(dp[i], j > 0 ? dp[j-1] : 0);
        }
    } 

int answer = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < dp.size(); i++)
    answer = max(answer, dp[i]);
```

I think the code should be pretty self-explanatory.